# Convert All Variables in a Dataframe to Numbers

Tags: r

Is there a fast way to convert all variables in a column to numbers, regardless of variable type? ie. if a column only had values "Yes" and "No", they would be converted to 0 and 1; columns with 3 values of "a", "b" and "c" would be converted to 0, 1, 2, etc.

The current df that I am using has the 9th column as "Yes/No".

EDIT:

Using Moody_Mudskipper's suggestion, I have tried:

```
RawData1 <- as.matrix(as.numeric(factor(RawData[[9]], levels = c("Yes","No"))) - 1)

dput(head(df,10))
structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = 
"noquote")
```

Comment: So are you trying to convert only the 9th column or all columns to numeric?

Comment: In this particular example it was just 9th column as a test drive, but in practice I'd have a lot of columns to do this for...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `factors` for this:

```
df <- data.frame(yn = sample(c("yes","no"),10,T),
                 abc = sample(c("a","b","c"),10,T),
                 stringsAsFactors = F
                 )

df$yn2 <- as.numeric(factor(df$yn,levels = c("yes","no"))) - 1
df$abc2 <- as.numeric(factor(df$abc,levels = c("a","b","c"))) - 1

#     yn abc yn2 abc2
# 1   no   b   1    1
# 2  yes   b   0    1
# 3   no   b   1    1
# 4  yes   a   0    0
# 5  yes   c   0    2
# 6  yes   c   0    2
# 7  yes   c   0    2
# 8  yes   a   0    0
# 9   no   c   1    2
# 10 yes   b   0    1
```

Comment: There are no headers in my df and it's the ninth column that I'm attempting to change from "Yes/No" to "1/0", and I have written this: 

df1 <- as.numeric(factor(df[[9]], levels = c("Yes","No"))) - 1

But that changed my entire df to 1s and 0s

Comment: please provide the output of `dput(head(df,10))` in your question

Comment: Edited the main question.

Comment: @MarshallGu to replace `df[[9]]`, you should do this instead: `df[[9]] <- as.numeric(factor(df[[9]], levels = c("Yes","No"))) - 1`

Comment: I just facepalmed. Thanks so much! 

New inquiry, related: this is a great solution if there's relatively few options for one variable, but what happens when a variable can be 50 different things? Is there a better soln?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Your `df` don't match mine when run with `set.seed(1)`. You might have forgotten to run them together.

Comment: Thanks @user , I got lazy and just deleted the seed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Moody's answer (+1) explains that you need to convert to factors, then to numeric

You can use `mutate_all` to change the class of all columns in your data frame

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(as.factor(.))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `Base R` solution to convert all columns:

```
# Added a numeric column to @Moody_Mudskipper's data example
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(yn = sample(c("yes","no"),10,T),
                 abc = sample(c("a","b","c"),10,T),
                 num = 1:10,
                 stringsAsFactors = F
)

df = data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x))))
```

One issue with this though is that it gives:

```
   yn abc num
1   2   1   1
2   2   1   2
3   1   3   3
4   1   2   4
5   2   3   5
6   1   2   6
7   1   3   7
8   1   3   8
9   1   2   9
10  2   3  10
```

which is not what OP wants, as he wanted factor/character variables to be converted to 0,1,2,3,... One can try to do this:

```
df = data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x))-1))
```

but then all numeric columns would be incorrectly subtracted by 1...Using `mutate_all` (as in @CPak's answer) has this same issue. What you can do instead is to use `mutate_if` to only convert columns that are factors/characters:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_if(function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x), funs(as.numeric(as.factor(.))-1))

# or this...
df %>%
  mutate_if(function(x) !is.numeric(x), funs(as.numeric(as.factor(.))-1))
```

Now, columns are correctly converted:

```
   yn abc num
1   1   0   1
2   1   0   2
3   0   2   3
4   0   1   4
5   1   2   5
6   0   1   6
7   0   2   7
8   0   2   8
9   0   1   9
10  1   2  10
```

Comment: But if he doesn't provide levels how to know what these numbers mean ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Im guessing he's trying to run a model/use a function which only takes numeric variables (like LDA)? In which case, all columns have to be numeric. But you're right, if thats not the case, having the original columns might be better.